# How to delete all content in laravel project?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to delete all content from the table in database using a delete method with an url:

```
Route::post('delete','receiptcontroller');
```

But I got an error Invalid route action:

```
[App\Http\Controllers\receiptcontroller]
```

The view:

```
<form action="{{ url('delete') }}">
    <input type="submit" value="delete" class="btn-danger btn-lg">
</form>
```

and method:

```
public function delete() {
    receipt::truncate();
}
```

Comment: check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#basic-routing and using this in your delete function `DB::table('users')->truncate();` based on laravel 5.6

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Route::post('/delete','receiptcontroller@delete');
```

Comment: yeah right, i totally forgot about it .Ok the error is gone but another one was appeared .Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message @Canor

Comment: In your form you need to specify what method you are using:

try `<form method="POST" ..>`

And actually when you are deleting anything you should send DELETE method. 
Remember to send csrf token as well.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf